# Java - Assign the correct number from list

Tags: java

I have a non-repeated Shuffled  list between 1 and 16 and a 2D array, What I'm trying to do is assing the number 16 to the position btn[3][3], all the other positions can have the other remaining list values (1 - 15)

**Code:**

```
int c = 0;
    int v = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        v=0;
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++){


            String number = Integer.toString(list.get(c));
            c++;

            if (i == 3 && j == 3){
                JButton btnmix = new JButton();
                btnBotonMix[i][j] = btnmix;
                btnBotonMix[i][j].setBounds(70+90*(i%10),v+90*(i/10),90,90);
                btnBotonMix[i][j].setText(number);
            }

            else{ 
                JButton btnmix = new JButton();
                btnBotonMix[i][j] = btnmix;
                btnBotonMix[i][j].setBounds(70+90*(i%10),v+90*(i/10),90,90);
                btnBotonMix[i][j].setText(number); 
            }

            v = v + 90;
        }
    }
```

What I'm looking for, is to always assign the number 16 in my index btn[3][3]

So I want get this (the number 16 always in [3][3] and all the remaining ones in a random position):

```
[0][0] 15
[0][1] 11
[0][2] 14
[0][3] 5
[1][0] 12
[1][1] 3
[1][2] 8
[1][3] 9
[2][0] 6
[2][1] 2
[2][2] 13
[2][3] 1
[3][0] 4
[3][1] 7
[3][2] 10
[3][3] 16
```

Comment: and your problem is? In order to recieve help you might want to include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, stacktrace and whatever goes wrong here. Everything that helps us to identify where you are stuck and why.

Comment: The if and else blocks are identical, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just added some details

Comment: Just change in your `if(i==3 && j==3)` :  `btnBotonMix[i][j].setText(16+"");` ?

Comment: @Furtiro, that might repeat the number 16, contrary to the idea that the list is non-repeated (the OP will decide whether it’s acceptable).

Comment: Sure, but his error is clearly and just here , it's just an idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // always put 16 last
    final int lastNumber = 16;
    // take it out from the list from the start
    list.remove(Integer.valueOf(lastNumber));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        v = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

            String number;
            if (i == 3 && j == 3) {
                number = Integer.toString(lastNumber);
            } else {
                number = Integer.toString(list.get(c));
                c++;
            }

            JButton btnmix = new JButton();
            btnBotonMix[i][j] = btnmix;
            btnBotonMix[i][j].setBounds(70 + 90 * (i % 10), v + 90 * (i / 10), 90, 90);
            btnBotonMix[i][j].setText(number);

            v = v + 90;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know -

```
int c = 0;
int v = 0;
Arrays.sort(list);//added
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    v = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        String number = Integer.toString(list.get(c)); //Changed
        c++;
        if (i == 3 && j == 3) {
            JButton btnmix = new JButton();
            btnBotonMix[i][j] = btnmix;
            btnBotonMix[i][j].setBounds(70+90*(i%10),v+90*(i/10),90,90);
            btnBotonMix[i][j].setText(number);
        } else { 
            JButton btnmix = new JButton();
            btnBotonMix[i][j] = btnmix;
            btnBotonMix[i][j].setBounds(70+90*(i%10),v+90*(i/10),90,90);
            btnBotonMix[i][j].setText(number); 
        }
        v = v + 90;
    }
}
```

I do not think now you would need if else here.

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way is to check if the number retrieved is 16 when you reach the position [3][3]

```
    int c = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<a.length; j++){
            String number = list.get(c);
            c++;
            JButton btnmix = new JButton();
            btnBotonMix[i][j] = btnmix;
            btnBotonMix[i][j].setBounds(70+90*(i%10),v+90*(i/10),90,90);
            if (i == 3 && j == 3){
                if(number.equals("16")){
                  btnBotonMix[i][j].setText(number); 
                }
            }
            else{ 
               btnBotonMix[i][j].setText(number); 
            }
        }
    }
```